# What are some real-world products or applications that can be developed using GANs?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, applications, generative-adversarial-networks

GANs have shown good progress across a wide variety of domains ranging from image translation, image generation, text to image synthesis, audio/video generation, image super-resolution and many more.

Although these concepts have great research potential, what are some real-world products or applications that can be developed using GANs?

A few I know are drug discovery and product customization. What else can you suggest?

Comment: Some months ago, the state-of-the-art model for drug design was actually based on VAEs (rather than GANs).

Comment: I'd advise having a look at [[2001.06937] A Review on Generative Adversarial Networks: Algorithms, Theory, and Applications](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.06937), especially the "Applications" section, 5.

Comment: Sure, thank you.